# Using new keyword throws error after node upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following test which worked fine in node v12.22.1.

After upgrading to node v16.16.0 it seems like the `new` keyword is no longer recognised.

Throwing following error:

```
/Users/username/projects/my-app/__tests__/components/ErrorComponent.spec.jsx:153
        const error = new Error();
                      ^

Error: 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/projects/my-app/__tests__/components/ErrorComponent.spec.jsx:136:23)
    at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/username/projects/my-app/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
    at /Users/username/projects/my-app/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper (/Users/username/projects/my-app/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
    at /Users/username/projects/my-app/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Could I get some advice on why this would happen? Thanks.

The test:

```
  it('should test', async () => {
    const error = new Error(); // fails at this line itself
    const submitFormPromise = Promise.resolve({
      json: () => {
        Promise.reject(error);
      },
    });
    submitForm.mockReturnValueOnce(submitFormPromise);

    // some assertions.
  });
```

Comment: I wonder if your testing framework redeclares `Error` somehow.

Comment: @robertklep Hm is just jest. No version changes to it though. Is just deleting node_modules + lock file. And npm i with node 16. Built fine. But throwing above error when running test.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use `new` when creating an `Error` instance, so a quick fix might be to just remove it. It's a strange issue, though.